# NSBundles loaded during runtime don't give resource paths

Tags: cocoa, lazy-loading, nsimage, nsbundle

i'm programming an app with cocoa that installs additional NSBundles during runtime. But i can't get any resources out of it. That's the code so far:

```
-(void)load {
    NSString *appSupportSubpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] builtInPlugInsPath];
    NSArray *bundlePaths = [NSBundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"bundle" inDirectory:appSupportSubpath];
    NSEnumerator *searchPathEnum;
    NSString *currPath;
    searchPathEnum = [bundlePaths objectEnumerator];
    NSMutableArray *classes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    while(currPath = [searchPathEnum nextObject])
    {
        NSBundle *pluginBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:currPath];
        if(![pluginBundle isLoaded]) {
            [pluginBundle load];
        }
        Class principalClass = [pluginBundle principalClass];
        if ([principalClass isSubclassOfClass:[AddOn class]]) {
            [classes addObject:principalClass];
        }
    }
    addOnLibrary = classes;
}

-(NSArray *)infos {
    NSMutableArray *infos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSEnumerator *enumerator;
    Class theClass;
    enumerator = [addOnLibrary objectEnumerator];
    while(theClass = [enumerator nextObject])
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [dictionary setValue:[theClass patchname] forKey:@"name"];
        [dictionary setValue:NSStringFromClass(theClass) forKey:@"classname"];
        [dictionary setValue:[theClass icon] forKey:@"icon"];
        //Here icon is nil for AddOns added during runtime
        [infos addObject:dictionary];
    }
    return infos;
}

//the addon-icon method
+(NSImage *)icon {
    NSBundle *myBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    return [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[myBundle pathForImageResource:@"icon.png"]];
}
```

Why are addons available from startup of the program have icons and addons that have been installed during runtime return nil for their icon?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`-[NSBundle pathsForResourcesOfType:inDirectory:]` doesn't take arbitrary directory names. It takes the name of a subdirectory of the bundle's Resources directory.

If you are trying to find plug-ins, then just enumerate the contents of `[[NSBundle mainBundle] builtInPlugInsPath]` yourself.

I think the basic problem is that every step of finding and loading plug-ins has failed, but you have not checked any of your assumptions, so you weren't aware of that. Finally, when you go to get an icon, you're getting `nil` for the bundle and not noticing.  Of course, when you ask it for its icon, you're messaging `nil` and getting `nil` back.